# scala lower and upper bounds

Tags: scala, generics

```
class Queue[+T](
    private val leading: List[T],
    private val trailing: List[T]
) {
    def append[U >: T](x: U) =
      new Queue[U](leading, x :: trailing) // ...
}

class Fruit

class oranges extends Fruit

class apple extends Fruit

class diffAppale

val q1: Queue[Fruit] = new Queue[apple](List(new apple), List())
//> q1  : Test.Queue[Test.Fruit] = Test$Queue@30c7da1e

q1.append(new Fruit)                            
//> res0: Test.Queue[Test.Fruit] = Test$Queue@506e6d5e

q1.append(new oranges)                          
//> res1: Test.Queue[Test.Fruit] = Test$Queue@96532d6

q1.append(new diffAppale)  // i want to restrict this             
//> res2: Test.Queue[Object] = Test$Queue@3796751b
```

Here i could add to append function what ever object i can , i can see the resulting type is  is demoted to a lowest common denominator

But i would like to have same behaviour as java, say def append[? super T](x: U) // here append function will take all  objects which are supertype of T ,How can i achieve similar one in scala (implement super and extend for generics like java)

Comment: Why is this a problem for you?

Comment: I want to add some Specific object types only via append function , which can be controlled by >:, <: .. Is it poissible ?

Comment: I think you are trying to think more complicated that needed. If your required return type in a specific case is `Queue[Fruit]`, it will anyway not allow you to return `Queue[Any]`. Most of the time it doesn't make sense to enforce additional type constraints artificially, when the program correctly type-checks. Anyway, as I suggest in the answer, if you really want this, just remove the variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to restrict this or why returning a more generic new immutable object poses a problem for you.

But if you don't want that variance, simply remove all the variance annotations:

```
class Queue[A](leading: List[A], trailing: List[A]) {
  def append(x: A) = new Queue[A](leading, x :: trailing) // ...
}

class Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit
class Apple  extends Fruit
class NotFruit

val q1: Queue[Fruit] = new Queue(List(new Apple), Nil)
val q2 = q1.append(new Fruit)  // ok
val q3 = q2.append(new Orange) // ok

q1.append(new NotFruit) // error - found NotFruit, required Fruit
```

---

As to the question:

> append function will take all objects which are supertype of T

This is what your original code already does. Note that `Any` is super-type of all types. Since the argument is in covariant position, it is always possible to pass a value with a sub-type of `Any` *for an argument of expected type* `Any`. That's life :) Scala just feels different than Java because it is built around declaration site variance and not use site variance (arguably a better decision than Java's generics).

If you want further constraints, you can ask for an evidence parameter such as

```
def append[B >: A](x: B)(implicit ev: B <:< Seedless): Queue[B]
```

Or put an upper bound (this cannot be the same as `A` because of `A`'s variance):

```
def append[B >: A <: Fruit](x: B): Queue[B]
```

**But:** it really doesn't make sense IMHO.

Comment: Now i am little confused :), You had removed the coverience of A(+A), But still you can add Queue[apples] to Queue[Fruit] as below

Comment: val q1: Queue[Fruit] = new Queue(List(new Apple), Nil)          But i could not add like below if coverience is removed                                                       val q1: Queue[Fruit] = new Queue[apple](List(new apple), List()), What is the difference !!!

Comment: @sharathchandra Scala (like Java) is a language with sub-typing. A parameter of type `A` can always be satisfied by passing a value of type `B <: A`. You don't need variance annotations for that, that's a "built-in" feature so to say. So if you have a `Queue[A]` with method `append(x: A)` you can always call that method with a value `y: B` if `B <: A`. That is sound by definition, because that method sees `y` as a value of type `A` and can safely treat it so, because `B` has every feature (member) that `A` has.

Comment: You cannot write `val q1: Queue[Fruit] = new Queue[Apple](List(new Apple), Nil)` without the variance annotation, because now a `Queue[Apple]` is no longer a sub-type of `Queue[Fruit]`. You can construct a `val q1: Queue[Fruit] = new Queue[Fruit](List(new Apple), Nil)` because `List[+A]` is covariant in its element type, so a `List[Apple] <: List[Fruit]`. Scala will correctly identify the expected return type `Queue[Fruit]` this way.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, use variance annotations if the usage of your type parameter allows it. Scala is a language with sub-typing and favouring immutable data types, using the variance annotations makes its use smooth. Don't worry that the return type might be "widened", e.g. to `Queue[Any]`, because in the next step you'll see that you will probably not going to be doing anything with such a type.

Comment: Thanks , It answered My Question ..The only doubt i was having it "widened", e.g. to Queue[Any], But what in case of Mutable objects , How we should handle such cases !!!

Comment: @sharathchandra In case of mutable objects you typically cannot use variance annotations (you'll see if you try). That's the advantage of immutability. Also in case of mutable objects, you wouldn't return a new queue but simply mutate the one you are calling into...